# How to reload the model when using this.get('store').query?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have a user model with attributes name and city, i am fetching 25 records at a time from server since there are lot of user records

so my routes has this

```
model(){
return this.get('store').query('user', {page:1}); }
```

which fetches me the first 25 records

Now in my template i have a button which on click hits the action to fetch the next 25 records ie

```
action:{
findMoreUsers(){
        this.get('store').query('user', {page:2});
    } }
```

Now in the browser, in the ember data the new records are loaded ie it shows 50 records

but when i try to do something like this.get('model'), it gives me the only the old records but not  the newly loaded records

So how to to refersh the model so that it shows me all the old as well as new records(50 records)?

Thanks

Comment: How do you want your URL ?. if you want to keep state in URL then prefer queryarams or dynamic segments. if you dont want to include anything in the URL then you can simply change model using set method

Comment: like a normal index url, ie localhost:4200/users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you haven't changed the model itself, which is just the result of a request to your server. I would recommend:

```

```
page: 0,

beforeModel() {
  return this._findMoreUsers();
},

model() {
  return this.get('store').findAll('users');
},

_findMoreUsers() { 
  this.get('store').query('user', { page: this.incrementProperty('page') });
}
```

```

Or something along those lines.

Then you can use `this.store.peekAll('users')` to retrieve all users that have been loaded into the store. If you need to *change* the model, you'll probably need to `this.get('model').pushObjects(...)`.

Comment: i m able to get all the data using the this.store.peekAll('users'), thanks

Comment: @Dom great! Feel free to mark as answer if you're satisfied